# Как передать в другой .c файл переменную?

Tags: c

Есть два файла **a.c** и **b.c**.
В **a.c** у меня реализована основная функция `main`, переменная `tratata` и содержится прототип функции `int foo(int n, int * a)`, больше никаких параметров в эту функцию я передать не могу. 
В другом файле **b.c** у меня произведена реализация данной функции, причем там должна использоваться переменная `tratata`. А как передать эту переменную (не как аргумент функции), я честно говоря не понимаю.

Comment: 1) сделать переменную `tratata` глобальной 2) показать код - может проблемы-то и нет вовсе.

Comment: В языке C передаются не переменные из файла в файл, а аргументы из функции в функцию.

Comment: @openspace  Покажите реальный код, в котором возникает проблема, и как эта переменная tratata используется в функции, если она там не объявлена?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Элементарный [пример реализации](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OvhxyEUE85LCKJfk):

```
int tratata = 42; // определение глобальной переменной

void f(void); // прототип функции из другого файла

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int tratata; // говорит о том, что переменная определена в другом файле

void f(void) {
    printf("%d\n", tratata);
}
```